# jQuery getting slider value from anonymous slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sliders

I'm looking for help with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/techii/9e2cJ/2/

and this is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671821/jquery-filter-with-multiple-criteria)

But because this isn't a "come here with your problem and we will do it for you" site I have one spesific question in particular

In the jsfiddle above I'm using anonymous sliders and the function reacting to slide/change is supposed to filter/match restaurants parsed from JSON. I'm trying to extract values from my four sliders, but they have to be matched to their respective vars e.g. ambienceSliderValue when collected so I can compare them to their JSON counterparts (ambienceRating)

```
var refreshRestaurant = 
    $(".restaurant > div").each(function(){
            // Some code to extract things like spicyness, expensiveness
            // this part should maybe be in the JSON object constructor above to push data? Perhaps I should use .val(); instead?
            var ambienceRating = $(this).data("ambienceRating");
            var spicyRating = $(this).data("spicyRating");
            var garlicRating = $(this).data("garlicRating");
            var expensiveRating = $(this).data("expensiveRating");

               // Also some code to get the slider values...


            var isMatch = ambienceSliderValue <= ambienceRating && spicySliderValue <= spicyRating && garlicSliderValue <= garlicRating && expensiveSliderValue <= expensiveRating;
            $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    })
```

Is my only solution to use named sliders?

Comment: `change` option in slider should be funcion...

Comment: It already is though isn't it? Refers to var refreshRestaurant which is a function.

Comment: no, it is `object` **`refreshRestaurant()
TypeError: object is not a function`**

Comment: how you would to relate sliders to `ambienceRating` , etc... if they not named any way ? by number of ?

Comment: so adding $(function () {rest of refreshRestaurant goes in here}); would make it a function correct?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. I guess you perhaps could make a for-loop that increases by 1 on each iteration and select them that way, but I guess just naming them is more straightforward.. Thanks for helping out btw!

Comment: yes, why not name them ? function here should be declared as `function refreshRestaurant  () {` if jsfiddle will work again, i'll show you demo

Comment: There is no harm in naming them, I just figured there would be a way to get values from anonymous sliders given that they use them in their examples. Here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ilevem/1/edit you mean this ?

Comment: Yes, like that. But in your current code, the sliders will just replace each other. I need them in seperate variables so I can filter them. Looks like named sliders are my only option if I want the output from each slider seperately.

Comment: just name them and update array like `variables[this.id]=$(this).slider('value');`

Comment: like [here](http://jsbin.com/ilevem/4/edit)

Comment: Fantastic, can you post the JSbin as an answer so I can upvote and accept? I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example I'll show variables update from callback function:

HTML:

```
<div class="sliders">
    <div id='a'></div>
    <div id='b'></div>
    <div id='c'></div>
    <div id='d'></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  var vars={};
    $('.sliders div').slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: refreshRestaurant,
        change: refreshRestaurant
    }); 

    function refreshRestaurant() {
     vars[this.id]=$(this).slider('value'); 
      console.log(vars);
    }
});
```

[DeMO](http://jsbin.com/ilevem/4/);